# Using a photo as <h1> in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, image-replacement

In my school, they said this was the way to go if we used an image as a title with a special font for ex. Now, I'm trying this but I don't really understand

1) why you should do it

2) it doesn't seem to show up unless it is given a specific height.

Can someone show me a better way to do it, while still doing this
 `<h1><span></span></h1>` thing?

```css
.title{
  background-image: url(...);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*it displays nothing now, only when I add a height here*/
}

.titlespan{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title"><span class="titlespan"></span></h1>
```

Comment: You wrote the class titlespan upside down

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote it fast here, it's not copy paste, it's correct on my real document though. I changed it.

Comment: There's no content here in your code that's the reason you need to define some height or width , Otherwise, it will take the height and width depending upon your content or image (whatever you have)

Answer (score 2):

If you want display an image instead of the text, that's enough for you:

```css
h1 {
  background-image: url(...);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100px /* Image width */;
  height: 25px /* Image height*/;
  text-indent: -9999px; /* This hide text*/;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
```

This technique is used to have a "SEO Friendly" text for the search engines, showing the user an image.

Comment: I'll try it out, and let you know something. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should *not* use `h#` for image only as these tags has special meaning. E.g. `h1` means *Title of the page*.

And yes, if you have only image as background, then you must set element dimensions (width is set to `100%` by default for all block elements).

I would use simple `div` for that (another option would be `<img>` tag that will auto-resize to source dimensions):

```css
#title {
  height: 50px;
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/50x50') repeat-x center center;
}
```

```html
<div id="title"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, from the viewpoint of a search engine I do not recommend using h1 tag simply to show an image either. But if you wish to simply set up a background for your actual title text, this solution works great. But do not leave the header tag empty or you should at least specify your page title in `<meta>` to improve SEO.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is content it will work, or you will have to give a height/width

```css
.title{
  background-image: url(https://media-exp1.licdn.com/media/AAEAAQAAAAAAAANbAAAAJDE5NjBkNDk1LTY3ZGQtNDA0NS04YTJiLTdkNmU3NjZiNjI3Mg.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*it displays nothing now, only when I add a height here*/
}

.titlespan{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title"><span class="spantitle">a</br>a</br>a</br>a</br>a</br>a</br>a</br></span></h1>
```

Comment: Oh, this could be it! I'll give it a shot and see what happens!

Comment: here there are two different class spantitle and titlespan

Comment: @NawazGhori As pointed out in my comment in the OP's question that was a typo introduced by him when he posted the areticle.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm a student and in school they said this was the way to go if we
>   used an image as title with a special font for ex.

Using an image with written text to replace a title in this way is not a good idea because the text (image text) may be seen differently on different screens due to dimensions and resolution.

The approach seems right if the image is only the background.
And the text is completed inside the `<span>` tags, which in turn are made visible instead of hidden.

And the special font can be set for the `h1` or the `span` in CSS. (In the example a font is linked from google fonts in the html)

```css
.title{
  background-image: url(https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fh260/back_pic/00/05/81/6456279a0080dd1.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align:center;
}

.titlespan{
  font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif; 
  color:white;
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text" rel="stylesheet"> 
<h1 class="title"><span class="titlespan">This is the title</span></h1>
```

Comment: Span is quite unnecessary in this situation, as you've only set out some basics like `font-family` and `color`, you could just set these out in `.title` and the result would be the same.

Comment: @ProDexorite Sure but the OP in the question asks not to change this